# How to animate a simple progress bar using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is a loading bar script in CSS... I want to animate it using a Javascript function... But I have no idea where to start?

Here is the code:

I have tried this CSS code to animate it but using CSS:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  cursor: default;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

body {
  background: #ffff;
}

#pb {
  background: #transparent;
  width: 250px;
  height: 38px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -19px;
  margin-left: -125px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

#progress {
  height: 38px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #0080FF;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #6db3f2;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6db3f2 0%, #54a3ee 50%, #3690f0 51%, #1e69de 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #6db3f2), color-stop(50%, #54a3ee), color-stop(51%, #3690f0), color-stop(100%, #1e69de));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
}

#done:active {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 6px;
}

#done {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 38px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #EEE;
  height: 38px;
  width: 250px;
  text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
}

#pb:hover #progress {
  transition: all 10.3s;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="pb">
  <div id="progress">
    <div id="done">Loading...</div>
  </div>
  Done!
</div>
```

But I want a Javascript function to animate the progress bar in 10 seconds.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What would you like to trigger the animation with? Would you still like to use the CSS transition?

Comment: I want to trigger the animation with execution of a function... If I could use javascript to animate the bar that would be great...

Comment: Just going to point this out: There are a bunch of great libraries like https://loading.io/progress/ to do this exact thing.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do this:

```
let elem = document.getElementById("done");   
let width = 1;
let id = setInterval(frame, 100);
function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
} else {
    width++; 
    elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
}
```

Also there is ProgressBar.js. You can check out [this site](https://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/) for more modern and good looking progress bars. It allows you to look the codes in JSFiddle and it is easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

You can trigger the animation of this function with javascript. You can even set its transition duration!

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector(".progress .bar").style.transitionDuration = "10s";
  document.querySelector(".progress").className += " complete";
});
```

```css
.progress {
  width: 50%;
  height: 2em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.bar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  
  transition-property: width;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}

.progress.complete .bar {
  width: 0%;
}

button {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <div class="bar">Loading...</div>
</div>

<button>
  Start
</button>
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer ... plus one... I got the idea of `.css("transition-duration", "10s");` please tell me how to select the bar in my own code? I tried     `$('#pb').css("transition-duration", "10s");` with no luck

Comment: Try `$('#progress #done').style.transitionDuration = "10s";` `.css` is method of jQuery.

Comment: @SaraRee Like Ömürcan said, it's a jquery helper. I'll edit my answer to use vanilla JS